# when i run the python file on startup using crontab i got the following error

Tags: python, cron, pyautogui

i installed the following packages,already
sudo pip3 install pyautogui.
and done the following settings in crontab,
@reboot XAUTHORITY=/home/pi/.Xauthority DISPLAY=:0  sh /home/pi/ICUmedical/launcher.sh >/home/pi/logs/cronlog 2>&1;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
import pyautogui as ui
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 241, in <module>
import mouseinfo
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/mouseinfo/__init__.py", line 223, in <module>
_display = Display(os.environ['DISPLAY'])
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/Xlib/display.py", line 80, in __init__
self.display = _BaseDisplay(display)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/Xlib/display.py", line 62, in __init__
display.Display.__init__(*(self, ) + args, **keys)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/Xlib/protocol/display.py", line 129, in 
__init__
raise error.DisplayConnectionError(self.display_name, r.reason)
Xlib.error.DisplayConnectionError: Can't connect to display ":0": b'Invalid MIT-MAGIC- 
COOKIE-1 key'
```

Comment: Is the Xserver running? Are you sure you have access to `:0`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply well i am new in linux so i don't know exactly what is Xserver and display :0.

Comment: The x server is the system responsible for graphic environment (windows, images, mouse cursor, etc) on Linux, which normally starts when the user logs in. If the cron job is started before that, it will not work. Also, the job has to be launched with enough permissions for that session (the root or the user that has logged in).